# Problem with starting the trigger in Oracle Apex Application

Tags: oracle-apex

I created triggers after creating a database in oracle apex. When testing in SQL code everything was fine, they worked. In the application I have the Professors table and when I change the value of the column "name", in the Courses table the value of the column "professor_name" should change. However when I change the value of the column "name" in the Professors table it throws me the error.
Here is the trigger definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER profesori_upd
 AFTER UPDATE OF ime on profesori
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN 
 UPDATE kursevi set ime_profesora = :new.ime
 where pr_jmbg= :new.jmbg_pr;
 END;
```

Here is the table Proffesors:

```
 CREATE TABLE PROFESORI( jmbg_pr VARCHAR2(13) PRIMARY KEY,
 ime VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 prezime VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
 id_spreme NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT profesor_sprema_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_spreme) REFERENCES 
 STRUCNE_SPREME(id)
 );
```

Here is the table Courses:

```
 CREATE TABLE KURSEVI( 
 opis VARCHAR2(40),
 id_jezik NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
 id_nivo NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
 pr_jmbg VARCHAR2(13) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT kurs_jezik_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_jezik) REFERENCES JEZICI(id_j),
 CONSTRAINT kurs_nivo_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_nivo) REFERENCES NIVOI_KURSEVA(id_n),
 CONSTRAINT kurs_profesor_fk FOREIGN KEY (pr_jmbg) REFERENCES PROFESORI(jmbg_pr),
 CONSTRAINT kurs_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_jezik,id_nivo,pr_jmbg)
         );
```

After denormalization I added columns ime_profesora and prezime_profesora to the table Courses:

```
ALTER TABLE KURSEVI
 ADD ime_profesora VARCHAR2(20); 
ALTER TABLE KURSEVI
 ADD prezime_profesora VARCHAR2(20);
 UPDATE KURSEVI SET ime_profesora=( SELECT ime FROM PROFESORI WHERE profesori.jmbg_pr=kursevi.pr_jmbg);
 UPDATE KURSEVI SET prezime_profesora=( SELECT prezime FROM PROFESORI WHERE profesori.jmbg_pr=kursevi.pr_jmbg);
 ALTER TABLE KURSEVI
 MODIFY ime_profesora varchar2(20) not null;
 ALTER TABLE KURSEVI
 MODIFY prezime_profesora varchar2(20) not null;
```

Error occurs after I try to change the value of the column name in the application, it does not say what the error is.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error you get. If it seems to be related to a trigger then include the trigger definition as well, and the table definitions.

Comment: You still haven't said what error you get. But your trigger won't compile; it [gets ORA-00904](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d32023e04830cbdc3e7e476ba246c53d) because your `kursevi` table doesn't have a `ime_profesora` column.